# Community home page redirect has stopped working

Tags: lightning, community, napili, redirect, winter21

I implemented a redirect from the community home page to the logged in user's account page on our customer community following this blog post: https://www.crmscience.com/single-post/2016/09/26/Dynamic-Navigation-in-Napili-Communities. It has been working fine but has recently stopped working - I suspect as result of Winter '21 release.  Now the home page doesn't redirect - url doesn't change and just displays the home page which is blank (its only content is the myAccountRedirect component).  I can't figure out why - can anyone shed any light on this?

Here is the code:

```
public class NapiliCommunityController {
@AuraEnabled
public static User getLoggedInUser(){
    return [SELECT Id, Contact.AccountId FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
}
```

}

```
<aura:component controller="NapiliCommunityController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.redirectToAccount}" />
```

</aura:component>

```
({
redirectToAccount: function(component, event, helper) {
    var loggedInUser;
    var state;
    var navEvt;
    
    var action = component.get("c.getLoggedInUser");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            loggedInUser = response.getReturnValue();
            navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
            navEvt.setParams({
                "recordId": loggedInUser.Contact.AccountId,
                "slideDevName": "detail"
            });
            navEvt.fire();
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Enable the NapiliCommunityController apex class to the profile the community user uses. After the Winter '21 release, Apex classes have to be added to the profiles.

Reference:https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_lc_restrict_apex_guest_users.htm